# get customer role nopcommerce

Tags: c#, razor, nopcommerce

Can anyone help me get customer role on a view in version 2.8? I have tried workcontext, and error says "workcontext does not exist in the current context". I have the following code below, but it does not work..

```
@model BoardsIndexModel
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Services.Helpers;
@using Nop.Web.Models.Boards;
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Customers;
@using Nop.Services.Customers;


@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators"))
{
    Do that;
}
else
{
    Do this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it, with the help of a nice person on the nopcommerce forum:

```
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Customers;
@using Nop.Services.Customers;
@using Nop.Core;
@{
    bool customerHasRoleX = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.IsInCustomerRole("Administrators");
    bool customerHasRoleY = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.IsInCustomerRole("ForumModerators");
}

@if ((customerHasRoleX == true) | (customerHasRoleY == true)) {

}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/login?ReturnUrl=%2fboards");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
@User.IsInRole("Administrators")
```

Comment: That did not work either. It behaves as such that user is NOT in role, but I know user IS in role, "Administrators".

Comment: Well I tried.....@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
    Do that;
}
else
{
    Do this;
}

Comment: This looked like a simple solution but unfortunately it didn't work for me either.